# Pyqgis: Make Layers Visible and invisible

Tags: python, layer, qgis, visible

I'm new at Python but for a school project, I have to write a small program, which, if it gets activated, makes an "invisible" layer visible. 
Seriously, I do not know, where to start. 
I tried it with that code:

```
QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot().findLayer(ocean()).setItemVisibilityChecked(False)
```

All I get is the:

> NameError: name 'ocean' is not defined

Ocean is the name of the Layer.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Make sure you post this in gis.stackexchange too, if you haven't already.

Answer (score 1):

```
prj = QgsProject.instance()
layer = prj.mapLayersByName('Adresspunkt')[0]
prj.layerTreeRoot().findLayer(layer.id()).setItemVisibilityCheckedParentRecursive(True)
```

Comment: For me that somehow sets other layers invisible also when using "False". To make a layer invisible i used `prj.layerTreeRoot().findLayer(layer.id()).setItemVisibilityChecked(False)`